# Triggering a service without using an Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a service that takes a screenshot of the android's screen, it is triggered through a button in the MainActivity, where I pass the resultCode and data.
But I would like to call the service without needing an Activity, is that possible? My idea is to run the service through a php api, but what worries me is the resultCode and data, that would tie me to an Activity. Is there a solution? Sorry for the bad English.

MainActivity.java

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startProjection();

            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                startService(com.security.system.appsecuritysystem.service.ScreenCaptureService.getStartIntent(this, resultCode, data));
            }
        }
    }

private void startProjection() {
        MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
            startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    }
```

ScreenCaptureService.java

```
public class ScreenCaptureService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "ScreenCaptureService";
private static final String RESULT_CODE = "RESULT_CODE";
private static final String DATA = "DATA";
private static final String ACTION = "ACTION";
private static final String START = "START";
private static final String STOP = "STOP";
private static final String SCREENCAP_NAME = "screencap";

private static int IMAGES_PRODUCED;

private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
private String mStoreDir;
private ImageReader mImageReader;
private Handler mHandler;
private Display mDisplay;
private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
private int mDensity;
private int mWidth;
private int mHeight;
private int mRotation;
private OrientationChangeCallback mOrientationChangeCallback;

public static Intent getStartIntent(Context context, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScreenCaptureService.class);
    intent.putExtra(ACTION, START);
    intent.putExtra(RESULT_CODE, resultCode);
    intent.putExtra(DATA, data);
    return intent;
}

public static Intent getStopIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScreenCaptureService.class);
    intent.putExtra(ACTION, STOP);
    return intent;
}

private static boolean isStartCommand(Intent intent) {
    return intent.hasExtra(RESULT_CODE) && intent.hasExtra(DATA)
            && intent.hasExtra(ACTION) && Objects.equals(intent.getStringExtra(ACTION), START);
}

private static boolean isStopCommand(Intent intent) {
    return intent.hasExtra(ACTION) && Objects.equals(intent.getStringExtra(ACTION), STOP);
}

private static int getVirtualDisplayFlags() {
    return DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
}

private class ImageAvailableListener implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try (Image image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage()) {
            if (image != null) {
                Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * mWidth;

                // create bitmap
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

                // write bitmap to a file
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mStoreDir + "/myscreen_" + IMAGES_PRODUCED + ".png");
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                IMAGES_PRODUCED++;
                Log.e(TAG, "captured image: " + IMAGES_PRODUCED);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }

        }
    }
}

private class OrientationChangeCallback extends OrientationEventListener {

    OrientationChangeCallback(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        final int rotation = mDisplay.getRotation();
        if (rotation != mRotation) {
            mRotation = rotation;
            try {
                // clean up
                if (mVirtualDisplay != null) mVirtualDisplay.release();
                if (mImageReader != null) mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);

                // re-create virtual display depending on device width / height
                createVirtualDisplay();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private class MediaProjectionStopCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.e(TAG, "stopping projection.");
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mVirtualDisplay != null) mVirtualDisplay.release();
                if (mImageReader != null) mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);
                if (mOrientationChangeCallback != null) mOrientationChangeCallback.disable();
                mMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(MediaProjectionStopCallback.this);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // create store dir
    File externalFilesDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
    if (externalFilesDir != null) {
        mStoreDir = externalFilesDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/screenshots/";
        File storeDirectory = new File(mStoreDir);
        if (!storeDirectory.exists()) {
            boolean success = storeDirectory.mkdirs();
            if (!success) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to create file storage directory.");
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to create file storage directory, getExternalFilesDir is null.");
        stopSelf();
    }

    // start capture handling thread
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            mHandler = new Handler();
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }.start();
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (isStartCommand(intent)) {
        // create notification
        Pair<Integer, Notification> notification = NotificationUtils.getNotification(this);
        startForeground(notification.first, notification.second);
        // start projection
        int resultCode = intent.getIntExtra(RESULT_CODE, Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        Intent data = intent.getParcelableExtra(DATA);
        startProjection(resultCode, data);
    } else if (isStopCommand(intent)) {
        stopProjection();
        stopSelf();
    } else {
        stopSelf();
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void startProjection(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    MediaProjectionManager mpManager =
            (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    if (mMediaProjection == null) {
        mMediaProjection = mpManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        if (mMediaProjection != null) {
            // display metrics
            mDensity = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            mDisplay = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

            // create virtual display depending on device width / height
            createVirtualDisplay();

            // register orientation change callback
            mOrientationChangeCallback = new OrientationChangeCallback(this);
            if (mOrientationChangeCallback.canDetectOrientation()) {
                mOrientationChangeCallback.enable();
            }

            // register media projection stop callback
            mMediaProjection.registerCallback(new MediaProjectionStopCallback(), mHandler);
        }
    }
}

private void stopProjection() {
    if (mHandler != null) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mMediaProjection != null) {
                    mMediaProjection.stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
private void createVirtualDisplay() {
    // get width and height
    mWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    mHeight = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    // start capture reader
    mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
    mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(SCREENCAP_NAME, mWidth, mHeight,
            mDensity, getVirtualDisplayFlags(), mImageReader.getSurface(), null, mHandler);
    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageAvailableListener(), mHandler);
}
```

}

Comment: You need a `context` to start a service, if you can pass contexts, you can use it to start the service.

Comment: Thanks, so I will need an Activity to start my service anyway.